# Codeigniter form validation external callbacks

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, callback, validation

I need to check if the `user_id` that was inserted exists. I was going to use callbacks in Codeigniter form validation but they require the function that does the validation be in the controller. I'm using this on many pages across multiple controllers so I thought I would do it in a model. Codeigniter doesnt support this though.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/205469/

I found this but it seems like a lot of code per validation. I'm using this alot so I dont want that big glob of code every time.

How can I run a form validation from a model with as little code as possible?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Colin how to call a external callback method

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/123780/ but its outdated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extend `CI_Form_Validation`. That way you will be able to call your callbacks just like all the other Codeigniter validation functions.

Comment: Are you saying make a `MY_Form_Validation` ?

Comment: This might sound dumb but where would that file go? And would i just have the function that does the validation? or would i need the `$config` stuff too?

Comment: Inside `application/core`. Read here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Wouldn't the file go in application/libraries ?

Comment: No. That was the directory in CI 1.7.

Comment: And the files inside core are loaded automatically, libraries you have to do it manually.

Comment: Just for everyone's FYI, one thing that tripped me up as I tried to extend the form validation library using `MY_Form_validation`, is to get rid of the `callback_` in the `->form_validation->set_rules(...)` since it is no longer a callback within a controller.